# Unable to redirect after login in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to redirect the user after login, but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) != "") {
  header("Location: Home.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee_login WHERE email = '$username'");
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  $newpass = $row['pass'];
  if ($newpass == $pass && !empty($row)) {
    $user_email = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user_email;
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    if ($_SESSION['username'] == "abc@gmail.con") {
      header("Location: admin/dashboard.php");
    }
    else {
      header("location: Home.php");
      exit();
    }
  }
  else {
    print_r("no");
  }
}
```

I am using the logic below to check if the user is logged in on the homepage.

```
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

}
else {

}
```

What have I done wrong, or what have I missed out that is stopping my redirect from working?

Comment: Yeah.  Don't ever use the mysql* functions

Comment: if($_POST['submit'])  this is right

Comment: Have you tried printing something out instead of using the header call, to ensure that your logic is getting you to the right place? Note that your last call to `header` passes "location" with a lower-case L.

Comment: Also, please Google "SQL injection attack", as you have a textbook case of it in your query. And it seems that you're likely storing your passwords as plaintext, not hashed, which is another very serious security concern.